# How to update entities atributes in new flutter program version correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm Flutter developer my question refers to the management of entities of a program in production that will receive an update.
If I have an application in production with an entity of 5 fields like this:

```
class TurmaEntity {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String imageURL;
  final DateTime createdAt;
  final List<String> listaGrupoComandoEnviado;

  TurmaEntity({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.imageURL,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.listaGrupoComandoEnviado,
  });
```

If I need to add an extra field (for example DateTime createdAt... to the program in the improved version... and then go update to google play... will generate an error because it is not compatible.

So my question is: how do I have the freedom to build new features for the program and being able to add new fields in the entities so as not to have errors?
Is there any professional way to do this?

I expect to developer new features and upgrade a new version of my program with no errors.

Comment: Would you elaborate? I couldn't reLly understand your question cuz I update my model class all the time when required

Comment: Share the error you face when you add a field in your model class.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called **migration**. When you migrate from 3 parameters to 4 parameters, your old code is no longer compatible. And so you can either:

- add the missing parameter to all of your old instances of the object on the back-end
- account for it on your front-end by adding something like this:

`name: data['name'] ?? 'John Doe';`

This way, if the parameter is missing, your code won't throw an error. This is called the **null-aware operator**. If the value on the left is **null**, the value on the right is the one that will be assigned.

You can also use other such tricks like:

`age: data['age'] is int ? data['age'] : 0;`